# Debian Squeeze on HP Pavilion d7 with Sandy Bridge and ATI 6740 - display problems

Tags: upgrade, ati, intel, debian

After a fresh install of Debian Squeeze 6.0.7 on an HP Pavilion d7 laptop - the option to install the `laptop` packages was checked on the installer - the monitor was not recognized on `gnome-display-properties`, that is, on `System > Preferences > Monitors`. The resolution was very low and couldn't be changed.

`lspci` outputed `Sandy Bridge rev 9` and `ATI 6740` as the VGA controllers. `uname -r` outputed `2.6.32-5-amd64` as the kernel. Doing some googling it seems that the `2.6.32` kernel does not support Sandy Bridge, and upgrading to wheezy seems to work. I don't want to upgrade, so I did some more research and installing `mesa-tools` was recommended, but that was already built-in. I tried installing ATI's proprietary drivers, that is, `fglrx-driver`, and rebooting, but that didn't solve the problem either.

So I gave up and tried to upgrade from squeeze to wheezy following [this guide](http://dodebian.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/upgrade-guide-edition-2-start.html), but it failed miserably - not only the kernel wasn't updated, some packages failed to install, others wouldn't open, and I had a lot of errors on boot-up. So...

1. Can this problem be solved in squeeze? If updating the kernel is absolutely necessary, how should I do it? The `2.6.38` and the `2.6.39` backports seem to work with those VGA controllers, but they are no longer available on the official backports, and `3.2` seems to have a few issues with squeeze.
2. If there is no option but upgrading to wheezy, how should I do it - that is, from squeeze, without needing to download a new netinst.

I'm currently downloading wheezy netinst from debian.org, which should solve all problems, but I've been using squeeze for so long on other computers and I really like the stability of it, so if it's possible to stay with squeeze that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proprietary fgrlrx drivers should work with that card in squeeze. The `fglrx-driver` package only includes the xorg module. A kernel module is also needed. The full instructions for configuring proprietary ATI drivers can be found on the [wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary).

In short you will do:

```
apt-get install fglrx-driver fglrx-modules-dkms fglrx-control
aticonfig --initial
reboot
```

The fglrx driver in squeeze supports the card, but the 6000 series was still relatively new when squeeze released. You may have better stability and performance using the versions from squeeze-backports.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I'll give it one more try when I get home and then give some feedback, thank you.

Comment: Well I tried it again, for some reason it didn't work. IDK, maybe I did something something wrong. I installed wheezy and it worked out of the box, but thanks for your answer.